# About shiny branch processing using outputUI

Tags: r, shiny

We are currently developing Shiny APP.
When Option A or Option B is selected from pickerinput
If you select Option A, an open file dialog opens. Then select the text file. When I select a text file, I want the title of the text file to be displayed.

When I select OptionB, I want to display nothing and do nothing.

I wrote a sample codee.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "Pi1",
    label = "SELECT!!",
    choices = list(c("OptionA"),
      c("OptionB")),
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 7),
    multiple = FALSE,
  ),
  
  uiOutput("button"),

  uiOutput("Message")
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  OutputUi_func(input,output)

   observeEvent(input$file, {

     volumes <- c("Documents"=Sys.getenv("HOME"))
      shinyFileChoose(input,'file', session=session,roots=volumes, filetypes=c('', 'txt'))

      if(length(input$file) <= 1) return({})

      fname <- unlist(input$file)
      fname <- c(fname[2][1])
      ftitle <- "FileName："
      fname <- paste0(ftitle,fname)

      output$filename <- renderText({
        paste0(fname)
      })
    })

}

OutputUi_func <- function(input,output){

  output$button <- renderUI({
    req(input$Pi1)
    if(input$Pi1 %in% c("OptionA")){
      shinyFilesButton('file', 'Read File', 'select file', FALSE)
    }else return(NULL)})
  

  output$Message <- renderText({
    req(input$Pi1)
    
    if(input$Pi1 %in% c("OptionA")){
      textOutput("filename")
    }else return(NULL)})
  

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code  has a problem.

・When I execute the code, I get an error about "cat".

・ Even if you select a text file,The file title is not displayed.

What should I do to avoid the above two errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "Pi1",
    label = "SELECT!!",
    choices = list(c("OptionA"),
                   c("OptionB")),
    options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE,size = 7),
    multiple = FALSE,
  ),
  uiOutput("button"),
  uiOutput("Message")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  OutputUi_func(input,output)
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    if(input$Pi1 %in% "OptionB") return(NULL)
    volumes <- c("Documents"=Sys.getenv("HOME"))
    shinyFileChoose(input,'file', session=session,roots=volumes, filetypes=c('', 'txt'))
    if(length(input$file) <= 1) return(NULL)
    
    output$Message <- renderText({
      if(length(input$file) <= 1 || input$Pi1 %in% "OptionB") return(NULL)
      sprintf("FileName：%s", unlist(input$file$files)[[3]])  
    })
  })
}

OutputUi_func <- function(input,output){
  output$button <- renderUI({
    if(input$Pi1 %in% "OptionA")
      shinyFilesButton('file', 'Read File', 'select file', FALSE)
    else return(NULL)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. The original source code is very long. Therefore, I want to make it a subroutine process. Can you tell me how to handle it in a subroutine?

Comment: That isn't too different. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.but code error [Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors]

Comment: Need to add one more check for that. See my updated answer. It works for me without any error, I tried various use cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering further questions.

When I ran the updated program, I got an error. "Error in [[: subscript out of bounds"

The error location is "sprintf (" FileName:% s ", unlist (input $ file $ files) [[3]])".

This R version uses 4.0.3. What version is your execution environment?

Comment: I am on 4.0.3 as well. I don't think R version is an issue. I just copy pasted the code from my answer and it works for me without any error. Are you sure you are copying it correctly? Try to copy it in chunks if you can't copy entirely.